# Select from fixed text pattern to 2nd blank line

Tags: awk, sed

Using sed/awk I want to select sections from a file that start with certain text until 2nd blank line. These patterns may occur multiple times in the file, all of which have to be extracted. For Example:

```
pattern1:
text1

text2

text3

pattern1:
text4

text5

text6

another text pattern1

more text
```

Desired result

```
pattern1:
text1

text2

pattern1:
text4

text5
```

I used a sed pattern

```
sed -n '/^pattern/,/^$/p' filename
```

This only selects until first blank line.

The awk pattern I found also does not work

```
 awk '/^pattern/,/^$/&&++n==2' filename
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Awk attempt is almost correct.   Here's a version that works by resetting the counter variable at the end of each group:

```
awk '/^pattern/||n=0,/^$/&&++n==2' filename
```

Note that this only resets the counter after a second blank line is found, so if there is only one blank line between occurrences of `pattern` then it will only print one line from the next group.

Comment: You don't need `~`. Just use `awk '/^pattern/||n=0,/^$/&&++n==2' file` or better `awk '/^pattern/||n=0,!NF&&++n==2' file`

Comment: Oops, you're right.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This `awk` solution should work for you:

```bash
awk '
/^pattern1/ {
   s = n = ""
}
!NF && ++n == 2 {
   print s
}
{
   s = s $0 ORS
}' file

pattern1:
text1

text2

pattern1:
text4

text5
```

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
pattern1:
text1

text2

text3

pattern1:
text4

text5

text6

another text pattern1

more text
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n"}/^pattern/{print;getline;print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
pattern1:
text1

text2

pattern1:
text4

text5
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that blank line (i.e. subsequent newlines) are both row separator and output row separator, therefore now one row can have multiple lines, when encountering row starting with `pattern` I `print` it, use [plain `getline`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Plain-Getline.html) to go to next line and `print` it.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 1):

```
/^pattern1:/ { n = 2 }
n > 0        { print }
NF == 0      { n--   }

$ awk -f filter.awk data.txt
```